# C-Server Behaves Irrationally

Tags: c

C-SERVER is designed to print "**ok**" when it receives "**111**"
**NOT ANYTHING ELSE.**

( I couldnt figure a way to remove **\n** so its **"111\n"** to be exact. )

```
echo '111' | nc <ip> <port>
echo 'TEST-OOO' | nc <ip> <port>
echo '111' | nc <ip> <port>
```

C-SERVER: ( above 3 are connected to the responses below )

```
111
ok

TEST-OOO

111
-OOO
```

**STRANGE** :  Why did it print **-OOO** ?

it is designed to print "**ok**" when it gets "**111**". not **-OOO**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h> 
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <err.h>
#include <string.h>

char outt[15];
char inn[100];

int main()
{
  int one = 1, client_fd;
  struct sockaddr_in svr_addr, cli_addr;
  socklen_t sin_len = sizeof(cli_addr);

  int sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
  if (sock < 0)
    err(1, "can't open socket");

  setsockopt(sock, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, &one, sizeof(int));

  int port = 85;
  svr_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
  svr_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
  svr_addr.sin_port = htons(port);

  if (bind(sock, (struct sockaddr *) &svr_addr, sizeof(svr_addr)) == -1) {
    close(sock);
    err(1, "Can't bind");
  }

  listen(sock, 5);
  while (1) {
    client_fd = accept(sock, (struct sockaddr *) &cli_addr, &sin_len);

    read(client_fd,inn,100);
    printf(inn);

    if (strcmp( inn, "111\n" ) == 0){
    printf("ok\n");
    }

    snprintf(outt, sizeof outt, "%s\n", inet_ntoa(cli_addr.sin_addr));


    if (client_fd == -1) {
      perror("Can't accept");
      continue;
    }

    write(client_fd, outt, sizeof(outt) - 1); /*-1:'\0'*/
    close(client_fd);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This code:

```
read(client_fd,inn,100);
printf(inn);
```

is undefined behavior.  `read()` does not terminate the received data with a NUL character.  In this case, the contents of `inn` from a previous iteration of your loop appear in the output *because they're still there*.

This would be better:

```
ssize_t bytesRead = read(client_fd,inn,sizeof(inn) - 1);
if ( bytesRead > 0 )
{
    inn[ bytesRead ] = '\0';
    printf(inn);
}
```

will print the data sent as a NUL-terminated string, *assuming* the client actually sent a C-style string without a NUL-termination.

Answer (score 0):

You're not checking the results from the call to `read()` to see how much has been read in.

Then you're not terminating `inn` so it's not terminating where you think it should be and instead contains part of the previous sent line.